# Azure VM backup

Tags: backup, azure, cloud, cloud-storage

I am wondering how Administrators are handling Azure retention of decommissioned servers.

We use our Azure infrastructure for development. Once we are finished with a server, I want to download the VM from Azure, but the speeds of taking the data down is slow. It downloads the entire disk, regardless of how much data is on it. What would be best practice of retaining these VMs?

Comment: Why download it locally for archival? Does Azure Backup not meet your requirements?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by downloading the disk? Maybe there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never download a disk, a better approach is to store it in an Azure storage account.
But if I would need to download it I would use [storage explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=windows)